# Add substring to a string in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following array:

```
SPECIFIC_FILES=('resources/logo.png' 'resources/splash.png' 'www/img/logo.png' 'www/manifest.json')
```

And the following variable:

```
CUSTOMER=default
```

How can I loop through my array and generate strings that would look like

```
resources/logo_default.png
```

depending on the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below uses [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to extract the relevant substrings, as also described in [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100):

```
specific_files=('resources/logo.png' 'resources/splash.png' 'www/img/logo.png' 'www/manifest.json')
customer=default

for file in "${specific_files[@]}"; do
  [[ $file = *.* ]] || continue               # skip files without extensions
  prefix=${file%.*}                           # trim everything including and after last "."
  suffix=${file##*.}                          # trim everything up to and including last "."
  printf '%s\n' "${prefix}_$customer.$suffix" # concatenate results of those operations
done
```

Lower-case variable names are used here in keeping with [POSIX-specified conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) (all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the operating system or shell, whereas variables with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use; setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so the conventions apply to both classes).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `sed`:

```
for f in "${SPECIFIC_FILES[@]}"; do 
    echo "$f" | sed "s/\(.*\)\.\([^.]*\)/\1_${CUSTOMER}.\2/p"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that there is only one period per filename, you can use expansion on each element directly:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${SPECIFIC_FILES[@]/./_"$CUSTOMER".}"
resources/logo_default.png
resources/splash_default.png
www/img/logo_default.png
www/manifest_default.json
```

If you don't, Charles' answer is the robust one covering all cases.